# Range reduction for trigonometric functions

Tags: algorithm, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement range reduction for trigonometric functions.
I found this paper http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/pcspa/2010/4180/00/4180b048-abs.html which talks about using 64-bit integer arithmetic.

The idea presented should work but there seems to be some problem with equations in the paper.
Is this efficient than the one implemented in fdlibm ?

Comment: You say "there seems to be some problem with equations in the paper" - what problems are they?

Comment: I can't read the paper referenced in the link; it's behind a paywall. Can you reword the question to enable other (non-academic) people to have some possibility of answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

Should you want to to perform a complete floating point range reduction, consult K.C. Ng's "ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit" readily findable on the web.

The salient issue is that to do range reduction on standard trig functions such as sine(x), where x is in radians, one must do a precise `mod` operation involving Pi.  The `mod` needs to extend 4/Pi out to enough factional bit places to have a meaningful result.   This paper details that process and how far one needs to go.  Turns out, it is potential 100s of bits, but not millions of bits.  Possible you are aware of this issue, but if not, it is what you need to know to make a *good* reduction using 64-bit routines or whatever.

Comment: In what non-contrived situations is "super-precise" trigonometric range reduction actually useful?  Certainly in most of the usage cases I've seen for trig functions, computation of the arguments entails multiplying by either the fraction 884279719003555/281474976710656 (nearest `double` to π) or some other value computed using that fraction.  An expression like `Math.sin(Math.PI/180.0*x)` would report the since of 180° as zero if argument reduction is performed using Math.PI; argument reduction using π does not improve precision.

Comment: One justification of "super-precise" trigonometric range reduction presented in _ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit_ is that the precision need is _not_ known by the implementor functions such as `sine(double x)`.  Code using functions such as `sqrt()`, do not expect answers that are many ULP off, but the best answer possible. Like-wise with `sine()`, the methods discussed present a way to provide great accuracy over then entire range of `x`.  Most applications do not need this. The paper discusses more rational, suggest reading it for a better answer.

Comment: @supercat "expression like Math.sin(Math.PI/180.0*x) would report the since (sic) of 180° as zero if argument reduction is performed using Math.PI": True.  But that would not be the best answer as `Math.sin(Math.PI)` is not 0.0.   e.g. `sin(3.14159265358979311600 /* Math.PI on my system */ ) --> 1.224647e-16`.  `1.224647e-16` is small difference from 0.0 in absolute terms, but as FP it typically logarithmically distributed, it is infinitely better than 0.0.

Comment: If the computation of the argument to `sin` is computed by multiplying something by a constant that is supposed to [but can't] equal π, optimal accuracy will be obtained if range reduction is performed using *whatever the value of π was considered to be in the multiplication*.  Given that the 8087 has an instruction to load a register with a value of π which is accurate to 64 bits, it performs range reduction using that 64-bit value.  When used with code that multiplies a value by a 52-bit approximation of pi, optimal accuracy would be obtained by performing range reduction with that value.

Comment: The fact that `Math.Sin(180.0 * (Math.Pi/180.0))` isn't zero should be classified as a tolerable quirk rather than a feature, since the sine of 180° is not 1.224647e-16, but should be *precisely* zero.  Further, unless code happens to know that the argument to sine represents a precise value, rather than one which is +/- 0.00000000000000001% (1/1000 of an ulp), any reported value of sin(x) which is between the sine of 0.9999999999999999999x and that of 1.0000000000000000001x should be considered as good as any other.  Unless the argument was computed using Kahan summation...

Comment: @supercat In the example of `sin(3.14159265358979311600)`, there was no multiplication as in "value of π was considered to be in the multiplication".  `sin()` was simple called with a value and it return the best possible answer.  That is the heart of the matter: `sin()` does not _know_ `Math.PI` was used in the construction of `x`.  `sin()` is providing the best (or at least good) answer it can assuming `x` is infinitely precise.  In any case, this discussion shows that value of having companion trig functions that compute based on 360 degrees of some exact period.

Comment: ...or some other similar means, I find it doubtful that the argument wouldn't have an uncertainty of *at least* 0.5ulp.  If the input to sin(x) has uncertainty of ±dx, the output cannot be expected to have an uncertainty of less than ±cos(x)dx.  As for your example, was that number produced without reference to a 52-bit approximation of pi?  I would think a much more realistic scenario would be code asking for e.g. sin(3.1415926535897932384626433832795), in which case the answer should be no greater than 5E-32, but instead receiving the sine of the value you quote.

Comment: In what non-contrived situations would code written in a language which doesn't support 64-bit floating-point values not have at least 1/4096 lsb of uncertainty in the argument to sin(double x)?  How often does a compute an argument for sin(x) without involving pi in the calculation somehow, in a fashion which avoids any uncertainty in the argument without having to carry out calculations using excessive precision?  In all realistic scenarios I can see, the only reason code would end up computing sin(x) for values larger than pi would be if...

Comment: "I find it doubtful that the argument wouldn't have an uncertainty of at least 0.5ulp."  All math operations are based on the assumption that the arguments are infinitely precise and the answers are rated on the ULP of the answer versus the infinitely precise result arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55219/discussion-between-chux-and-supercat).

Comment: @supercat "If the computation of the argument to sin is computed by multiplying something by a constant that is supposed to [but can't] equal π ..." -- this is an *excellent* point, but (IMO), the conclusion isn't that we should compromise the accuracy of sin( ), but rather that libraries should also provide sinpi(x), which computes sin(πx) with good accuracy.

Comment: @StephenCanon: I won't dispute that there should exist a standard sin2pi function; my point is that I would say that a function which, given x, will return a value which is precisely equal to the sine of some value within 0.5ulp of x, should be considered no less useful than one which returns a value within 0.5ulp of the sine of precisely x.  In cases where the second would take longer to compute, such extra computation is a waste of effort.

Comment: @supercat  If i follow your commnet, if `|x|` is so large that 0.5 ulp of `x` exceeds 2pi, the return value of `sin(x)` could return anything [-1 to 1].

Comment: @chux: Yup.  I recall there were some Intel chips where sin(x) with x greater than 2^64 would simply yield x, and I don't think that should be allowed since it's not in the range +/-1, but otherwise any value in that range should be considered equally good.  I can think of cases where code might require that the sine of even a garbage value not yield a number outside the range +/-1, or require that repeated calls with the same value give the same answer, but none that would otherwise care what value was returned.

Comment: @supercat: it turns out that it's *not* prohibitively expensive to return a well-rounded result for arbitrary inputs.  All of the fastest math libraries do the computation right (meaning, deliver a well-rounded result), because that computation is not wasted.

Comment: @supercat: All intel chips return x from FSIN and FCOS if the input is outside of the valid range (-2^63, 2^63).  This is because FSIN is not meant to be a complete implementation of sin( ).  Instead, it's intended that it be combined with FPREM to perform argument reduction into that range.  However, in practice it's faster to simply use software implementations rather than these instructions (even implementations with fully correct argument reduction are a few times faster), so modern math libraries don't use them.

Comment: @supercat & inestimable Stephen Canon:  "K.C. Ng's "Argument Reduction For Huge Arguments: Good To The Last Bit" is the type of approach that provides quality results without excessive computation time.  Certainly correct `sin(x)`  for huge values of `x` have limited value, yet the magnitude at which that happens is arbitrary.  So with a reasonable efficient method that provides a provable good answer over the entire range of `x` is a good thing.  This way the user can decide when trig results of a large `x` are moot rather than the library.  Enjoyed reading your views

Comment: @StephenCanon: In what scenarios would a sine function which returned a result that was within 0.5ulp of the exact sine of x be more useful than one which returned a result that was exactly equal to the sine of some value that was within 0.5ulp of x?  I know the extra cost of the former is not huge, but I'm curious in what cases is it worth *anything*?